# Is this the right definition of an Assembly?

Tags: .net, metadata, manifest, cil, .net-assembly

**.NET Assembly = MSIL + Manifest + Metadata**

Is this the right definition of an Assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's missing resources too.

But other than that, yeah. There's the assembly manifest, type metadata, MSIL (implements the types defined in the assembly), and resources.

Note that ONLY the manifest is required. You can have an assembly missing any of the other elements (it's just a useless assembly though without type metadata and implementing MSIL or without resources).

Note that an assembly does NOT need to made up of a single file (the manifest could point to additional files containing parts of the assembly (for example, a resource)).

Comment: What it most important thing in assembly ? is it MSIL?

Comment: have you any MSDN reference in support of your answer or any other link or document?